# Is there a way to persist my tab groups between browser sessions in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, tab-groups

I find the new tab groups feature of Firefox 4 amazing and useful, but what I don't find amazing and useful is the fact that your tab groups are not persisted between sessions of opening and close and re-opening the browser.

Is there a plugin to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Firefox 4 will not prompt you when you close your browser like you were in Firefox 3.
It implicit assume user wants to close the browser without saving the tab.

To bring back the function, simply open a page to **about:config** and set **browser.showQuitWarning;false** to **true**.

I wish there is a button to enable this, but the trick above worked for me.

Comment: That did it!  I don't know why they don't enable that by default it almost makes the feature useless.